# Using ViewPager, CardView and RecyclerView with Fragments

Tags: java, android

I want to make a restaurant menu where I have 3 pages (1 for meat courses, 1 for fish courses and 1 for beverages) and I can swipe between them.

The lists should be inside a card like the following image: [Card Layout (bear in mind the dishes are in Portuguese)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqOT1.png)

Data Class:

```
package com.example.avaliacao2;

public class Data {
    public String[] pratos_carne = {"Frango Assado     6,5€", "Bitoque     7€", "Lasanha     6€"};

    public String[] pratos_peixe = {"Douradinhos     5€", "Atum á bolonhesa     7,5€", "Pastéis de bacalhau     6€"};

    public String[] bebidas = {"Água     1€", "Coca-Cola     1€", "Cerveja     1€"};
}
```

MainActivity Class:

```
package com.example.avaliacao2;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.viewpager.widget.PagerAdapter;
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.example.avaliacao2.fragments.PageFragment1;
import com.example.avaliacao2.fragments.PageFragment2;
import com.example.avaliacao2.fragments.PageFragment3;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ViewPager pager;
    private PagerAdapter pagerAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        List<Fragment> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new PageFragment1());
        list.add(new PageFragment2());
        list.add(new PageFragment3());

        pager = findViewById(R.id.pager);
        pagerAdapter = new SlidePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), list);

        pager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
    }
```

SlidePagerAdapter Class:

```
package com.example.avaliacao2;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;

import java.util.List;

public class SlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private List<Fragment> fragmentList;

    public SlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragmentList) {
        super(fm);
        this.fragmentList = fragmentList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return fragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragmentList.size();
    }
}
```

PageFragment1 Class (All 3 Fragment Classes are like this except for name and xml layout):

```
package com.example.avaliacao2.fragments;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import com.example.avaliacao2.R;

public class PageFragment1 extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup)inflater.inflate(R.layout.page_1, container, false);


        return rootView;
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager>
</LinearLayout>
```

page_1.xml (Again, All 3 Fragments have the same structure except for the text inside the TextView):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/pratos_de_carne"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="32sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

So far, I've made the swiping action and the fragments work and I tried researching and didn't find anything concrete.

Comment: but you didn't utilize the Data class

Comment: @Zain I was going to use it for the RecyclerView

Answer (score 0):

If you've already done the Pager, you just need to use a `recyclerView` in each fragment that you can slide, and fill it with your data lists

Comment: Do I need to also put a CardView inside each fragment? Because I want the data list to appear inside a CardView using RecycleView

Comment: If you want to, yes you'll need to add a `CardView` and inside it you add a `RecyclerView`